# "Could not open" Error Reading a CSV file in Perl

Tags: perl, csv

Whenever I try to open a CSV file using the open command:

`open(DAT, $file) || die("Could not open $file!");`

I'm getting the error:

`Could not open 1\file1.csv!`

Comment: Write `die("Could not open $file!: $!");` to get the error message as well.

Comment: Also, use a filehandle variable and use the 3-argument open: `open(my $fh, "<", "$filename")`.

Comment: As a final though, check out `Text::CSV`.

Answer (score -1):

does the variable $file has correct path of the required file?
If not, mention path of the file like '/home/folder/filename.format'